# How can I count the number of instances per a queryset? Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm writing an action to set one field equal to the number of instances attached to it via a foreign key (see below)

## Models.py

```
 class competition(models):
    competition_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

 class people(models):
    competition = models.ForeignKey(competition)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

## Admin.py

```
def people_in_competition:
     for X in queryset:
         X.number_of_people = X.count(X.set_all) #(I want the number of people in this competition in this part)
         X.save()
```

Of course this gives me an error as I cant seem to use _set_all in admin.py, does it only work in templates? What would be the best way to figure that number out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [backward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
X.number_of_people = X.people_set.all().count()
```

Comment: in order for that to work, I had to remove the X.count in front of it but iit worked THANKS!!!

Comment: Sorry for the inattentive answer. I copied code from the question and forgot to remove the excess code.